# How to Achieve On-Demand Generation of Dynamic Routes in Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, getstaticprops, getstaticpaths

In my Next.js 13 project, I'm working on implementing dynamic routes where the server initially calls an API when a page is **first visited**.

If the corresponding data entry exists, I want the server to generate the HTML page so that it's ready for **subsequent visits without regeneration**.

However, **if the data entry doesn't exist**, I'd like to redirect the visitor to a 404 page.

Here is how I used to achieve this in Next.js 12:

```js
export const getStaticPaths = async () => ({
  paths: [], //generating all pages on-demand
  fallback: true,
});

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  try {
    const { id } = context.params; // Getting the id from the URL
    const ArticleData = await ArticleApi(id); // API call
    return {
      props: {
        ArticleData: ArticleData.data, // Sending the data returned by the API to the page
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    // if an error occured on api call
    return {
      notFound: true, // Redirect to 404
    };
  }
}

export default function Article({
  ArticleData,
}) {
  if (!ArticleData) return <div>Loading...</div>; // While the server is making the API call

  return (<>page code </>)
}
```